# C++: How to pass array of objects into function?

Tags: c++, pointers, reference

I have a pointer to array of objects. It looks like:

```
MyClass *myClass[ 10 ];
myClass[ 0 ] = new MyClass(); // init for each of myClass[0..9]
myClass[ 0 ]->field1 = "hello";
```

How can I pass "myClass" to a function by reference? I tried a few cases but it didn't work.

Comment: That's an array of pointers. You should prefer `std::array<MyClass, 10>` especially when passing it into a function.

Comment: it's my fault. I meant myClass instead of obj.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you really must use an array, then

```
template<size_t N >
void foo(MyClass (&arr)[N] )
{
  // Access arr[i], size is N
}

...

foo(myClass);
```

Otherwise, use an `std::array`

```
template<size_t N >
void foo(std::array<MyClass,N>& arr )
{
  // Access arr[i], size is N or arr.size()
} 

...

std::array<MyClass, 10> myClass = ....;
foo(myClass);
```

I would not call an array "myClass" though.