# How to pass in an array of objects: error c2146: syntax error : missing ')' before identifier 'myMembers'

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, object

I'm a c++ student and this is my first post here.

I have an array containing `Member` objects (which will be dynamic in the future). I'm trying to pass the array into a function, `getLogin` in my case.

I think I have some of the syntax wrong, I'm still struggling to understand dynamic arrays and correct syntax for pointers in different situations. Visual Studio is showing an error with `myMembers`, where it is written as a parameter for `getLogin`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "Member.h"
using namespace std;

int getLogin( const int, Member[] );

int main(){

    int numAccounts = 0;
    int accCapacity = 5;
    int currentAcc = 0;

    Member member[5];

    currentAcc = getLogin( numAccounts, member );
    return 0;
}

int getLogin( const int lastAcc, Member[] myMember ){
    int accNum;
    cout << "account number:" << endl;
    cin >> accNum;

    if( accNum > 0 && accNum <= lastAcc ){
        myMember[accNum].setLoggedIn( true );
    }
    else{
        accNum = 0;
    }
    return accNum;
}
```

(p.s. What I really want is a pointer to the array, because I don't want a copy of the entire array to be created. However, I believe that using the array name is actually like using a pointer to the first element. So I think I don't need to worry about that.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17604164/c-how-to-pass-array-of-objects-into-function

Comment: Hmm.. I'm reading that question now. However, it looks like their answer suggests using this format for the function: int getLogin( const int lastAcc, Member (&myMemberArr)[] ) But I'm not sure what to put in for the size of the array..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the definition of `getLogin()` as follows:

```
int getLogin( const int lastAcc, Member myMembers[] ){
    //...
}
```

(And of course you should better use `std::vector` or `std::array`, but since this is a homework, this advice probably makes no sense)

Comment: Isn't std:: pointless with: " using namespace std" ? You're right, I'm totally unfamiliar with that haha.

Comment: @Rengetsu `using namespace std` [is considered bad practice](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/3959454)

Comment: @Rengetsu I didn't mean you are unfamiliar with this, just that the use of standard C++ containers is often prohibited for students

Comment: Oh I see, that is very interesting. I appreciate you taking the time to say so.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass an array of pointers then you have to change
the implementation of your function getLogin:

```
int getLogin( int lastAcc, Member** myMembers )
{
    int accNum;

    if( accNum > 0 && accNum <= lastAcc )
    {
        myMembers[accNum]->setLoggedIn( true );
    }
    else{
        accNum = 0;
    }
    return accNum;
}
```

and this is how you pass an array to it:

```
int numAccounts = 0;
int accCapacity = 5;
int currentAcc = 0;

Member* members[numAccounts];
for ( int i =0; i < numAccounts; i++)
{
  members[i] =  new Member();
}

currentAcc = getLogin( numAccounts, members )
```

Comment: it doesn't seem that he wants an array of pointers, he just wants to have the array of objects accessible in the function.

Comment: @Matt you're correct. I wasn't trying to pass in an array of pointers, but it's interesting to see it as an example. Thanks!

Comment: if your application will be dynamic in the future then passing pointers may be the way to go. You will be creating a new instance of the same object everytime. So passing it around as a pointer is much efficient.

Comment: Oh I see. Thank you, I'll have to think about how to implement a dynamic array of pointers then :)